# Complex analysis questions

Tags: complex-analysis

If $f$ is holomorphic on a region $U$ and derivative of $f$ is non vanishing on $U$ then for each $z$ in $U$ there exists a disc $D(z)$ around $z$ on which $f$ is injective.

My attempt: first I fix $z$ in $U$ and assume that it is not true. Then for each $r$ positive there exists at least two distinct points in the disc of $r$ around $z$ on which $f$ takes same value. But I couldn't proceed further.

Answer (score 1):

If we consider the functions as real function(from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^m$), then it is just a kind of inverse function theorem. But this can be proved in complex-analytic sense, too. We use Rouché's Theorem.

Suppose $z_0\in U, f'(z_0)\neq 0$, and let $w_0 = f(z_0)$. Since zeros are isolated, there is a deleted neighborhood $\{z:0<|z-z_0|\le r\}$ s.t $f(z_0)-w_0$ is nonzero. Since $f'(z_0)\neq 0$, the function $f(z)-w_0$ has simple zero at $z_0$. The curve $C = \{z:|z-z_0|=r\}$ is mapped to a curve near $w_0$ by $f$, but does not cross $w_0$. Hence $$\varepsilon = \inf\{|f(z)-w_0|:|z-z_0|=r\}$$ is positive, since the circle is compact set. Then for any $w$ with $|w_0-w|<\varepsilon$, we have $$|w-w_0|<\varepsilon\le |f(z)-w_0|$$ on the circle $|z-z_0|=r$. This inequality allows us to use Rouché's Theorem, and the function $(f(z)-w_0)+(w_0-w) = f(z)-w$ has the same number of zeros as the function $f(z)-w_0$ in the disk $\{z:|z-z_0|<r\}$, which is just $1$ since there are no other zeros than $z_0$, and the zero is simple. Therefore, preimage of $w$ under the function $f|_{\{z:|z-z_0|<r\}}$ is a singleton, and $f$ is injective on a (with possibly smaller radius than $r$) neighborhood $N$ of $z_0$, which is a subset of an open set $\{z:|z-z_0|<r\}\cap f^{-1}(\{w:|w-w_0|<\varepsilon\})$ containing $z_0$.